# Entity Framework Core - Inserting One-Directional Parent Child Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Since Table Per Type isn't available in Core, I had to do a bit of a workaround to get my entities how I like them. Essentially I have a base class with its properties, and a navigation property to its parent:

```
 public class Provision
{
    public Guid ProvisionId { get; set; }
    public string ProvisionName { get; set; }
    public string ProvisionDescription { get; set; }

    public Provision(){}
}

 public class CompanyLeaveProvision 
{
    public Guid ProvisionId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Provision Provision { get; set; }

    public CompanyLeaveProvision() { }
}
```

Configurations:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Provision> builder)
    {
        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(t => t.ProvisionId);

        // Properties
        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);

        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionDescription)
            .HasMaxLength(500);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionId).HasColumnName("ProvisionID");
        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionName).HasColumnName("ProvisionName");
        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionDescription).HasColumnName("ProvisionDescription");
        builder.ToTable("Provision", "Organization");
}

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CompanyLeaveProvision> builder)
    {
        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(t => t.ProvisionId);

        // Properties 
        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionId)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.CompanyId)
            .IsRequired();


        // Table & Column Mappings
        builder.ToTable("CompanyLeaveProvision", "Organization");
        builder.Property(t => t.ProvisionId).HasColumnName("ProvisionID");
        builder.Property(t => t.CompanyId).HasColumnName("CompanyID");


        builder.HasOne(t => t.Provision).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Provision>(t => t.ProvisionId);



    }
```

My context:

```
ProvisionContext: DbContext, IContext    {
    public DbSet<Provision> Provisions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyLeaveProvision> CompanyLeaveProvisions { get; set;} 
    // OnModelCreating and other code below
 }
```

I have a foreign key constraint on the the `Organization.CompanyProvision` table that references the `ProvisionId` property on the `Organization.Provision` table.

What is happening is the `CompanyProvision` is being inserted before the base `Provision`, resulting in this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_CompanyLeaveProvision_Provision". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Dev", table "Organization.Provision", column 'ProvisionID'.

To attempt to save, here is the code I am calling:

```
    _context.Entry(command.Provision.Provision).State = EntityState.Added;
    _context.Entry(command.Provision).State = EntityState.Added;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Aside from calling `SaveChanges()` after `each _context.Entry(MyEntity).State = EntityState.Added`, is there any way around this issue? I would prefer to have these save at once. I know a stored procedure is also an option, but I would prefer not to do that.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because this fluent mapping

```
.HasForeignKey<Provision>(t => t.ProvisionId)
```

is telling EF Core that `Provision` is the *dependent* entity and has FK to the principal entity `CompanyLeaveProvision`, while the database model is the opposite.

So simply change `Provision` to `CompanyLeaveProvision`

```
.HasForeignKey<CompanyLeaveProvision>(t => t.ProvisionId)
```